How to solve $y = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{W} \mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{W}$
I have a large number of pairs $(\mathbf{x}, y)$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector and $y$ is a scalar. These pairs satisfy the equation $y = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{W} \mathbf{x}$, where the matrix $\mathbf{W}$ is of interest.
One possible approach is to compute $\mathbf{x}' = \text{vec}(\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T)$ and solve $y = \mathbf{x}' \mathbf{W}$. This transforms the problem into solving a linear system. However, this approach leads to a square dimensionality, making it challenging to obtain a practical solution. Additionally, I am considering that the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ (concatnation of vectors $\mathbf{x}'$) is not full rank and is not sufficient to obtain the exact $\mathbf{W}$.

Do you want a $W$ that satisfies $y=x^TWx$ for a single pair $(x,y)$ or for a bunch of them? The existing answers address only the former but it seems like you are interested in the latter.

Oh, yes, I mean the latter. Do you have any advice?

I take it that you mean $y = x^TWx$. I'm sure there are infinitely many solutions to this problem, but if you just want one, take $W = y(x^Tx)^{-2}xx^T$. The matrix $(x^Tx)^{-1}xx^T$ is the projection to the line spanned by $x$.
A simpler solution is $W = y(x^Tx)^{-1}I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I might be blind, but I think you should replace $y$ with $y^{-1}$.

Yes, thank you @ClemensB!

Can I assert that computing the inverse of $(x^T x)$ is unavoidable? I am considering this because the ill conditioning prevents me from obtaining a meaningful result. BTW, what does $(x^T x)^{-2}$ mean?

I'm sorry if the notation is convoluted; I mean only $1/(x^Tx)^2$ by that. And in general you would have to divide somehow with some square of $x$.

Yes, in matrix notation, vectors are normally regarded as columns. That makes $x^Tx$ and $x^TWx$ scalars. The formula I wrote solves the equation since $x^T y(x^Tx)^{-2}xx^Tx = y(x^Tx)^{-2}x^Tx x^Tx = y$.

Thanks, I understand!

In a lot of contexts, a symmetric solution is desirable because of the real eigenvalues. So, imo this is the best solution.

Yes but the method of the solution is important not the solution verification in general.

The equation rewrites to
$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{j=1}^d w_{i,j}x_ix_j.
$$
If $x$ = 0, any matrix is a solution or no matrix is a solution, depending on what $y$ is. If $x$ has exactly one non-zero element, say $x_1$ wlog, then $w_{1,1} = y/x_1^2$ and $w_{i,j}=\text{anything you like}$ else is a solution. If there are more non-zero elements, you need to be a bit more careful with setting $w_{i,j}$, but it must be obvious now. Note that if $W_1$ is a solution and $W_2$ is a different solution, any convex combination $\lambda W_1 + (1-\lambda)W_2$ is also a solution.

Thanks, it helps!
